# Removing Prior Crontabs

Tags: cron, cgroup

I think I have competing cronjobs. When I run "sudo service cron status" I get the following output:

> Main PID: 31130 (cron)
>
> > CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
> >
> > > ```
> > >     |-11690 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
> > >       |-11691 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
> > >       |-11692 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cron_key=
> > >       |-11693 /usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cron_key=
> > >       |-11695 /bin/sh -c wget -O - -q -t 1 http:// myDomain/sites/all/modules/contrib/elysia_cron/cron.php?cron_key=
> > >       |-11696 wget -O - -q -t 1 http:// myDomain/sites/all/modules/contrib/elysia_cron/cron.php?cron_key=
> > >       |-11713 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
> > >       |-11714 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cron_key=
> > >       |-11715 /usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cron_key=
> > >       |-31130 /usr/sbin/cron -f
> > > ```

The different cron jobs were entered and edited using "crontab -e". I thought the edit would overwrite the previous entry, but when I view "syslog" they show up as follows:

> Feb 3 11:03:01 TMC-Website CRON[12082]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cr$
>   Feb 3 11:04:01 TMC-Website CRON[12092]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cr$
>   Feb 3 11:04:01 TMC-Website CRON[12095]: (ubuntu1) CMD (wget -O - -q -t 1 http: //myDomain/Site$
>   Feb 3 11:05:01 TMC-Website CRON[12112]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cr$
>   Feb 3 11:06:01 TMC-Website CRON[12126]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cr$
>   Feb 3 11:06:01 TMC-Website CRON[12129]: (ubuntu1) CMD (wget -O - -q -t 1 http: //myDomain/Site$
>   Feb 3 11:07:01 TMC-Website CRON[12137]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cr$
>   Feb 3 11:08:01 TMC-Website CRON[12146]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/curl http: //myDomain/cron.php?cr$
>   Feb 3 11:08:01 TMC-Website CRON[12149]: (ubuntu1) CMD (wget -O - -q -t 1 http: //myDomain/Site$

So you can see the pattern. I don't know if this is an issue, or how to remove all but the cron ran under user "ubuntu1".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer below work out for you ?

Answer (score 1):

To remove cron jobs belonging to another user:

```
$ sudo su [-l] other-user-name  # if other-user-name is a login user (option -l)
        # ^  ^ brackets indicate that you can just as well not use the option -l
$ crontab -e
... suppress the cronjobs that you identify as dupes or superfluous
... quit your crontab editor.
```

To remove root cron jobs:

```
$ sudo -i crontab -e 
... suppress the cronjobs that you identify as dupes or superfluous
... quit your crontab editor.
```

To remove present user's cronjobs (for the sake of completion):

```
$ crontab -e
... suppress the cronjobs that you identify as dupes or superfluous
... quit your crontab editor.
```

NOTE: `cron` will automatically take the new crontabs into account.

NOTE: Rather than to downright delete the lines corresponding to what you identify as spurious cronjobs, you might first want to simply comment them out. In a week time, after you've had time to check that "all is well", you can proceed with the actual deletion by revisiting the crontabs as shown above.